# I can't seem to model my data to a cubic function

Tags: python

I've recently been trying to model my data according to separate equations. This function should take some data (xdata and ydata) and fit it as best it can to a cubic equation, but it seems to be giving the wrong answers, and I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. For example when given xdata from 1 to 4 and the ydata of the first 5
4 cubes, it returns:

(array([[ 1.00000000e+00, -2.17381668e-12, -2.20122021e-12, -2.16174470e-12]]))

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

from scipy import optimize

xdata_string = input("Enter your values for the xdata")
ydata_string = input("Enter your values for the ydata")

xdata = xdata_string.split()
ydata = ydata_string.split()

#convert input to numbers
    for i in range(len(xdata)):
          xdata[i] = float(xdata[i])

    for i in range(len(ydata)):
          ydata[i] = float(ydata[i])


def curve_fn(x,a,b,c,d):
    return (a*(x**3))+(b*(x**2))+(c*x)+d


def cubefit(xdata,ydata):
    
    answer_string = sp.optimize.curve_fit(curve_fn,xdata,ydata)
    
    #debug
    answer_string = answer_string[:1]
    print(answer_string)
    
    return np.array(answer_string, dtype=float)

cubefit(xdata,ydata)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "it returns: ..." okay; and **why is that wrong**? What should the result be instead, and why? Please read [ask] and make sure to *ask a question*.

Comment: If you were expecting, for example, `array([[1, 0, 0, 0]])` then *you got the correct answer*, within tolerance. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken, or https://0.30000000000000004.com/.